# how to add two numeric strings?

Tags: string, excel, vba

I am trying to display in a cell a numeric string value with the char "0" at the beginning.
this is my code:

```
    Sub test2()
    Dim text As String
    text = Range("A1").Value
    Range("a1").Value = "0" & text

    End Sub
```

if the value in A1 is with letters it works fine (e.g. from "a" to "0a")
if the value in A1 is numeric it displays only the first numeric value (e.g. from "11" to "11" instead of "011"

Comment: You'll need to format the cell as text or prefix the value with `'`

Comment: @TimWilliams: That is a valid answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach to take depends upon:

1. Whether you want to use VBA or a worksheet formula. In your example you have VBA, but it is perhaps not mandatory, or even to be avoided if possible (this is usually my choice, unless VBA is required).
2. Whether you want the result to be numeric or string (you asked for a string, and it is the easier option).

A non-VBA, which gives you a string (from an integer number or a string in cell A1), is

```
="0"&TEXT(A1,"0")
```

With VBA, use the solution by TimWilliams (`Range("a1").Value = "'0" & text` instead of the last line of your code).

Comment: I don't understand. if it's a non VBA does it still have to be in visual basic? if not where do i put it?

Comment: @עמוסרום - It is a worksheet formula (not visual basic; as said, it is usually my choice, unless VBA is required). If your source number is in cell A1 (as your sample code shows), then type the formula that I provided in any other cell. You will not need VBA. PS: It's good to have autocompletion for the name, I wouldn't know how to type Amos...